# Java: nice way to stop threaded TCP server?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrent-programming

I have the following structure for TCP client-server communication:

- On server startup server starts
  acceptor thread, that accepts client
  connections and passes ServerSocket
  to it.
- When a client connection    arrives,
  acceptor thread calls    accept() on
  ServerSocket and submits    client
  processing job to worker    thread
  (by executor/thread pool) and provides client socket to it.
- Worker    in loop reads data from
  client socket    stream, processes it and sends replies.

The question is how to gracefully stop the whole system? I can stop acceptor thread by just closing ServerSocket. It will cause accept() blocking call to throw SocketException. But how to stop workers? They read from stream and this call is blocking. According to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) streams does not throw InterruptedException and thus worker cannot be interrupt()'ed.

It looks like I need to close worker socket from another thread, right? For this, socket should be made a public field or a method should be provided in worker to close it. Will this be nice? Or may be my whole design is flawed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model works appropriately.  The best way of interrupting non-interruptable constructs like IO is to close the socket.  You can of course handle it before you go into a blocking state, but if the IO functions don't react to interruption you dont really have many good options

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a boolean flag that the workers check periodically.  Call the flag `shouldStop` and if it's set to true, the worker cleans up and then dies.  Following this method would allow you to implement some clean-up code so you don't leave resources hanging, etc.

Comment: Best practice is to use Thread.interrupted(). This is standard solution which will work correctly in ThreadPool.

Comment: @Andrey Vityuk  Thread.interrupted is actually not great practice because it reset the interruption flag.  You may have meant Thread.interrupt or Thread.isInterrupted.  That being said, as I said in my answer, many IO constructs do not take thread interruption into account so (though I partially agree with your comment) it doesnt hold in this situation.

Comment: @Andrey Interrupting a thread that is blocked reading from a socket will not interrupt it. Yhe only way to close the thread is closing the socket and catching the exception SocketException to do some clean ups.

Answer (score 2):

You must not simply stop the server. The shutdown process might take a while while cleanup occurs because you need to ensure consistency.

Imagine a database server, if you simply shut it down while it is carrying out transactions you may leave its data inconsistent. That's why it typically takes a while to shutdown the server.

- You must first stop accepting new
  connections in the server.
- Then you can either wait for the
  current    worker threads to finish
  their work    and then close the
  server and    shutdown officially.
- Or you force the    worker threads to
  close their    connections with the
  client (probably    using some sort
  of flag as    suggested). This might
  imply some cleanup to leave data
  consistent, for instance revert
  trasnsactions or any kind of changes
  you have done in files or in memory.

Closing the connections with the clients in the server side should cause the clients to get a EOF on their sides as far as I understand.

**[EDIT-1]**

I have delved a bit on the issue, just because I had not used sockets in a while and because I found the question interesting. I think as it has been well pointed out by others, the only option is to close the socket, which according got Javadocs will automatically close the input and output streams/

If there are chances that the thread is not IO-blocked, but in wait state or sleeping, I think it is still recommended to issue a Thread.interrupt() for the corresponding worker thread of a given socket; because there cannot be certainty of the blocking of state of every thread.

```
public static class IOServerWorker implements Runnable{

        private Socket socket;

        public IOServerWorker(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String line = null;
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while( (line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                //TODO: do cleanup here
                //TODO: log | wrap | rethrow exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand this very well. "Then you can either wait for the current worker threads to finish their work" - if you read my question again, you will see that this is a problem. Workers can be blocked by reading from socket stream. And the question is how to gracefully interrupt them. Flag will not work here because worker cannot check it while in blocked I/O state

Comment: “You must not simply stop the server.” Actually, if you've got your server design right (ACID transactions and all) just stopping it will work. A change that results in a database commit is deemed to have happened, and a change that isn't, never happened. Making this work well is one of the good reasons for separating the database from the middle-tied business logic and web front end.